# Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient()

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am completely new with exact target. Please help with this error :

> Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient(): I/O warning : failed to load
>   external entity "ExactTargetWSDL.xml" in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\exacttarget\wp-content\themes\twentyfourteen\FuelSDK-PHP-Dot9\ET_Client.php
>   on line 76
>
> Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'ExactTargetWSDL.xml' : failed to load external entity
>   "ExactTargetWSDL.xml" in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\exacttarget\wp-content\themes\twentyfourteen\FuelSDK-PHP-Dot9\ET_Client.php
>   on line 76

Answer (score 1):

In Config.php, add 'xmlloc' => 'D:\xampp\htdocs\exacttarget\wp-content\themes\twentyfourteen\FuelSDK-PHP-Dot9/ExactTargetWSDL.xml'

Download https://webservice.exacttarget.com/ETFramework.wsdl and save it to a file in your root directory (D:\xampp\htdocs\exacttarget\wp-content\themes\twentyfourteen\FuelSDK-PHP-Dot9/) with the name ExactTargetWSDL.xml.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the 'ExactTargetWSDL.xml' in your system user's temp directory (Example C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp). It works for me. Refer below screenshot.

[image: Example C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp]

Note: This is a default configuration, we have our own custom path as well.

[image: As you can see in below screenshot, I have assigned a path to ExactTargetWSDL.xml file]