# 'SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'ExactTargetWSDL.xml' : failed to load external entity "ExactTargetWSDL.xml"

Tags: marketing-cloud, wsdl

This is a Salesforce Marketing Cloud / Exact Target question.  I know it has been asked before in all the places that I have linked to below, but none of those worked for me.  The ExactTargetWSDL.xml file is in my root directory (in fact, at this point its in several directories because of the different answers saying it should be in different places).  I have my ET_Client request set up like so

`$this->client = new ET_Client(true, false, ["clientid" => $clientId, "clientsecret" => $clientSecret])`

where as, per the readme, the first arg is the Refresh WSDL boolean that will automatically load a copy of the WSDL whenever its updated.

Things I've tried: 
[Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient()](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/56581/warning-soapclientsoapclient)

[Fuel SDK PHP version: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'ExactTargetWSDL.xml](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/71209/fuel-sdk-php-version-soap-error-parsing-wsdl-couldnt-load-from-exacttargetw)

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008sFlIAI

https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-PHP/issues/50

Is there something with permissions that I'm missing maybe?  Thank you for any help

Comment: Check if you are pointing to the correct WSDL https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getting_started_developers_and_the_exacttarget_api.htm